# get the variable value from the admin view in the model yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-modules

This is code at view admin

```
<h2>User: <?php echo $user->id ?></h2>
```

in view appears 3 as user id

this in model

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $doc = $user->id; //desc id
    if(Yii::app()->user->id=='1'){
        $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
        $userLogin = $user->login;

        $criteria->addCondition("user_id= $doc");
    }
```

$doc is undifined,,
how get value  $user->id from view admin

Comment: Not sure what you want. Can you describe more details ?

Comment: i want get $user->id for value $doc as condition 

like         $criteria->addCondition("user_id= $doc");

Comment: Why don't you pass the param from your controller to model

Answer (score -1):

Implement your user class with IdentityInterface 
 [yii\web\IdentityInterface](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-identityinterface)
In your configuration file

```
'user' => 
[
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', 
]
```

Then You may use this code to get user id in your view files as

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
if (!empty($user){
   echo "<h2>User: {$user->id}</h2>";
}
```

Comment: where i can put indentityclass in yii1?